# How to fix the mail sent (whoosh) sound when disappearing intermittently, especially after iTunes is opened?

Tags: email

The "whoosh" sound continues to disappear intermittently, especially after iTunes is opened.

- I've restarting my iMac restores the sound but usually not for long.
- I've Googled and searched for solutions and have found similar
  complaints but no lasting solutions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to explain 'disappear intermittently' a bit further. Do you mean that after you computer has been on for some time / after opening iTunes you never hear it anymore at all?

Comment: This is a strange issue, and to be honest, it is the first time I have heard of it happening. Have you attempted a disk permissions repair?

Comment: Whenever I open iTunes, the sent mail whoosh always stops working until I restart.  The intermittent part comes in because sometimes I haven't opened iTunes and the mail whoosh has stopped working for some other reason until i restart.

Comment: I am finding that the mail sounds fail after about 24 hours all the time. I constantly have to reset the sounds as described above every single day. I hope there is a fix for this.

Answer (score 3):

I got my whoosh back. I lost my mail whoosh after updating to 10.7.2

I resolved it by going into mail preferences, general tab & changing the sounds to "none" and unchecking "play sounds for other mail actions".

Then I quit mail from the top menu bar. I restarted mail, went back into preferences did the opposite: changed sounds to "new messages sound" and checked "play sounds for other mail actions", I then quit mail again from the top menu and then reopened it. Magically, my whoosh was back.

I don't know why it went away after updating. And I don't know why this fixed it, but it did.

Comment: File this one under 'W' for Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The whoosh disappeared from mail and I finally figured out that it was because I had earphones plugged into the Audio line-in port. I pulled that plug and the whoosh was restored.

Answer (score 0):

I too had lost me 'whoosh' after upgrading to Mountain Lion, but got it back by quitting and re-launching Mail.

Re-launching Mail has not proved the solution to another Mail-related problem, however. I have a Rule with an associated (special, individualised) sound attached. Since the ML upgrade, this sound pops up without warning, irrespective of whether or not a rule-matching message has arrived.